# Passing parameter with underscore : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript

I have a function that returns a div when its called.

```
function docTypetbl(indx) {
  return '<div><INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="_1_1_15_1_' + indx + '_SavedValue" VALUE="' + document.getElementsByName('_1_1_15_1')[0].value + '"><INPUT CLASS="valueEditable TKL" TYPE="TEXT" ID="_1_1_15_1_' + indx + '" NAME="_1_1_15_1_' + indx + '" VALUE=" ' + document.getElementsByName('_1_1_15_1')[0].value + '" SIZE="32" ONKEYUP = "getTKLResults(event,this.value, myForm,_1_1_15_1,15,"755204_0",1,0)"  ONCLICK= "getTKLResults(event,this.value,myForm,_1_1_15_1,15,"755204_0",1,0)"><div ID = "DTKL__1_1_15_1" style="position: absolute;"><table ID = "TKL__1_1_15_1"></table></div></div>';
};
```

The problem is with the onclick and onkeyup events. The parameter "755204_0" throw errors when used with `""`.
I tried giving `''`, but get "Invalid or unexpected token"

Answer (score 0):

Your error is nested double quotes here: "755204_0"

I suggest:

1. Use template literal
2. Use data-attribute
3. simplify oninput="getTKLResults(this)"

then the function can get values and data-attribute from the element

```js
function docTypetbl(indx) {
  var val = document.querySelector('[name="_1_1_15_1"]').value;
  return `<div>
  <input type="hidden" name="_1_1_15_1_${indx}_SavedValue" value="${val}">
  <input class="valueEditable TKL" type="text" id="_1_1_15_1_${indx}" 
         name="_1_1_15_1_${indx}" value="${val}" size="32" 
         data-code="755204_0" oninput="getTKLResults(this)" />
  <div id="DTKL__1_1_15_1" style="position: absolute;">
    <table id="TKL__1_1_15_1"></table>
  </div>
</div>`;
};
```